# Which query function used for result of count in postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am using php for fetching the result from a Postgres database and using the following query

```
pg_query($connectionstring , "select count(1) from emailCharacterstics where column = 'ready' ;");
```

It gives me NULL instead of return the count of ready.

Comment: Is it a problem with sql or php? Are you using correct connection string?

Comment: is your table really called `table`?

Comment: Yes I cross check the query others query work fine but if you query the count then it will give null

Comment: This is not a valid SQL statement, because `TABLE` is a reserved word. If you *really* have a table with that name, you'll have to use it with double quotes in SQL: `"table"`.

Comment: Putting the obvious syntax errors aside: that SQL query can never return NULL - there must be something else you are not telling us.

Comment: For example purpose I put the table name I know it is reserved word @laurenz Thank you for respond

Comment: @PraveenMourya ... I see you just edited this question. Do you still have issues?